# Tv antenna turns by itself

Tags: television, tv-antenna

Our TV antenna turns by itself.  The inside controller is unplugged and the antenna still turns.

Not just a bit but a full quarter turn and back.  Sometimes it will point west and sometimes south or east. It will stop for a short time and start up again. Any solutions?

Thanks for all of your comments.   Ed, do you mean to touch the wires on the inside controller together?  Won't that ruin the antenna motor???

Comment: The antenna is on a rotator?

Comment: Was it windy? Loose clamps?

Comment: Get the antenna in position and pull the wires from the rotor control and short them together this acts like a break and should stop the drift on the motor.

Answer (score 2):

If the rotator has a separate power injector in addition to the controller, make sure that is unplugged also. If all power to the rotator is cut, and the antenna is still rotating on its own, there are 2 possibilities:

1. The rotator motor or its gearing could have gone bad. Something could have broken from use over time or some extra strong wind that now causes that much slop to be in the mechanism. Probably the only fix is to replace the rotator. It seems that the recommended course of action would be to try and find a new old stock type model, as they have a much better reputation than the ones made today. I can't vouch for this personally though.
2. The clamps holding the antenna to its pole or the rotator to its pole could have loosened over time. Just get up on the mast and tighten everything up again.

Comment: Those clamps are usually on the small size and the nuts might be seized.  Would suggest having replacements before going up.  Does not take much for a heavy handed person to just snap them off.

Answer (score 1):

I went to the top of the pole and put a screw through the part that was moving into the pole to stop mine from turning because we get a lot of wind down here in Metairie, Louisiana.